# Chroot SFTP Users

Tags: ubuntu, ftp, sftp, users, chroot

I have an Ubuntu Server, where several users log in to upload some files. Each user has a home directory, in which I 'd like to be chrooted.

e.g. user1 connects with sftp to the server and is located at his home directory (e.g. /var/www/user1) and I 'd like him to be unable to "see" outside of this directory. Is there any easy way to handle this?

Comment: If you downvoted this question, please comment and say why. I don't see an obvious reason for the downvote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can, look for `ChrootDirectory` by `man sshd_config` in your system, unless your `sshd` is too old.

Comment: From memory, it's SSH 4.8p1 where they added this.  If you want an LTS release you'll have to go for 12.04.

Comment: You are right about the sshd version, I just googled the openssh server log and it is there. Thanks!